# Retrofit override method failure

Tags: java, android, retrofit

I am new to android programming and I am trying to connect to server with retrofit and get some data. I made a little example just to check if it would return some data. First there is a problem that I don't know if I even wrote the code to do what I want and second I get the errors:

"Error:(64, 52) error:  is not abstract and does not override abstract method failure(RetrofitError) in Callback"
and 2 errors " Error:(67, 13) error: method does not override or implement a method from a supertype"

Here is my code

```
 public class MainActivity extends ListActivity{
public static final String ENDPOINT = "http://tinoba.hostzi.com";
List<Jelovnik> jelovnik;
Button gumb;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    gumb = (Button)findViewById(R.id.gumb);



}

public void stisni(View view) {
    RestAdapter adapter = new RestAdapter.Builder()
            .setEndpoint(ENDPOINT)
            .build();
    JelovnikAPI api = adapter.create(JelovnikAPI.class);
    api.getFeed(new Callback<List<Jelovnik>>() {


        @Override
        public void onResponse(Response<List<Jelovnik>> response, Retrofit retrofit) {
            jelovnik = response.body();
            gumb.setText(jelovnik.get(0).getIme().toString());
        }

        @Override
        public void onFailure(Throwable throwable) {

        }
    });
}
```

}
and my retrofit interface

```
public interface JelovnikAPI {
@GET("/read.php")
public void getFeed(Callback<List<Jelovnik>> response);
```

}

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The version of `Callback` you are using is from `Retrofit 2` and you are still using `Retrofit 1.x`. [Callback](http://static.javadoc.io/com.squareup.retrofit/retrofit/1.9.0/retrofit/Callback.html) has two methods, `failure` and `success`. Your callback should look like

```
new Callback<List<Jelovnik>>() {


    @Override
    success(List<Jelovnik> t, Response response) {

    }

    @Override
    public void failure(RetrofitError error) {

    }
});
```

Comment: Thank you, I had 2 versions imported and that was the problem

Answer (score 0):

Replace `Throwable` with `RetrofitError`:

```
@Override
public void onFailure(RetrofitError retrofitError) {

}
```